# countdown never reaches 0 and gives negative value

Tags: javascript

I have a count down script, but I have 2 issues. 1. my countdown never reaches 0 and stops so i get a continous negative number. 2. the counter only displays in chrome and not firefox or internet explorer.How do I fix these two isses?

```
var sec, min, hr, day, timer, expireDate;

sec = 1000;
min = 60 * 1000;
hr = 60 * 60 * 1000;
day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
timer;
expireDate = new Date('Mon Sep 17 2012 14:26:00 GMT-0700');

timer = setInterval(function() {
    var currentDate, countdown, days, hours, minutes, seconds;
    currentDate = new Date();
    countdown = expireDate - currentDate;
    if (countdown === 0 ) {
        window.clearInterval(timer); 
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
    }

    days = Math.floor(countdown / day);
    hours = Math.floor((countdown % day) / hr);
    minutes = Math.floor((countdown % hr) / min);
    seconds = Math.floor((countdown % min) / sec);
    console.log(countdown);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
}, 1000);​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by others, you should be using `< 0`.

In addition, once your expired condition is met, you are immediately overwriting the `EXPIRED!` label, so you will never see it.  You will need to move the code following the `if` into an `else` or simply return within the `if`.

```
if (countdown <= 0 ) {
    window.clearInterval(timer); 
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
} else {
    days = Math.floor(countdown / day);
    hours = Math.floor((countdown % day) / hr);
    minutes = Math.floor((countdown % hr) / min);
    seconds = Math.floor((countdown % min) / sec);
    console.log(countdown);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
}
```

And finally, the reason it wont' work in IE is likely the `console.log`.  IE will fail on this if you do not have a console open at the time.  Simply remove the `console.log` line and this works just fine in IE.

Answer (score 2):

In these two lines:

```
currentDate = new Date();
countdown = expireDate - currentDate;
```

You're getting the difference between the current time and the expect time *to the nearest millisecond*!

If it doesn't hit exactly the right value, it'll go right past it.

Change the `===` test to `<=`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing times to the millisecond!  You'd have to be amazing lucky to make this work:

```
currentDate = new Date();
countdown = expireDate - currentDate;
```

Try:

```
if (countdown < 0 ) {
```